# How to create array of seven days from Wednesday until Friday to change on Friday at 10 am

Tags: php, date

That is:

If now less than 10:00 on Friday this week, creating array containing the Saturday of the previous week, followed on Sunday, Monday, Tuesday, Wednesday and Friday of this week.

If now is more than 10:00 on Friday this week, replacing the previous array by another array containing Saturday of this week, followed by Sunday Monday Tuesday Wednesday and Friday of next week.

I can not express in a script, the logic of this situation.

Thank You

After reading many, many post I come to this that does not work

```
$current_time = strtotime('now');
$week_start_day = "friday";
$start_time = "10:00";

if ($current_time <= strtotime('$week_start_day this week $start_time')) {
    $day_1 = date('d/m/Y', strtotime('previous week friday', strtotime(date('d-m-Y'))));
    $day_2 = date('d/m/Y', strtotime('previous week saturday ', strtotime(date('d-m-Y'))));
    $day_3 = date('d/m/Y', strtotime('previous week sunday  ', strtotime(date('d-m-Y'))));
    $day_4 = date('d/m/Y', strtotime('previous week monday', strtotime(date('d-m-Y'))));
    $day_5 = date('d/m/Y', strtotime('previous week tuesday', strtotime(date('d-m-Y'))));
    $day_6 = date('d/m/Y', strtotime('this week wednesday  ', strtotime(date('d-m-Y'))));   
    $day_7 = date('d/m/Y', strtotime('this week thursday ', strtotime(date('d-m-Y')))); 

} 
else{

    $day_1 = date('d/m/Y', strtotime('this week saturday  ', strtotime(date('d-m-Y'))));
    $day_2 = date('d/m/Y', strtotime('this week sunday', strtotime(date('d-m-Y'))));
    $day_3 = date('d/m/Y', strtotime('this week monday', strtotime(date('d-m-Y'))));
    $day_4 = date('d/m/Y', strtotime('this week tuesday  ', strtotime(date('d-m-Y')))); 
    $day_5 = date('d/m/Y', strtotime('this week wednesday ', strtotime(date('d-m-Y'))));    
    $day_6 = date('d/m/Y', strtotime('this week thursday ', strtotime(date('d-m-Y'))));
    $day_7 = date('d/m/Y', strtotime('this week friday ', strtotime(date('d-m-Y'))));
}


echo "
    $day_1 <br> 
    $day_2 <br>
    $day_3 <br>
    $day_4 <br> 
    $day_5 <br>
    $day_6 <br> 
    $day_7 <br>     
    ";
```

Comment: What is not working with your script? Well, you're doing the same thing over and over again here. Couldn't you just set the start date and use `+1 day` for the rest 6?

Comment: With that I take only seven days from today.
But the situation is more complex.
You must understand the situation if you help me to solve

Answer (score 0, accepted):

if i understand you correctly this is what you want have not tested it  very well so might have bugs but this is the idea.

```
$fri=strtotime(" Friday this week + 4 hours ");// 10:00 GMT 
$now=time();

$week=array();

if($now<=$fri)
{
    $day = "last Saturday";
}
else
{
    $day = "next Saturday";
}

for($i=0;$i<7;$i++)
{
    $week[] = date("d/m/Y", strtotime($day." +".$i." day"));
}

foreach($week as $day)
{
    echo $day;
}
```

Comment: You have perfectly understood my situation and you've solved perfectly and elegance.

I just fixed two bug.

First line: $fri=strtotime(" Friday this week + 10 hours ");// 10:00 GMT

In the second "for": $ week [] = date ("d / m / Y", strtotime ("next Saturday +" $ i "day")..);

These corrections are correct?

Comment: echo $fri and copy the value and then go to http://www.epochconverter.com/ to see what the values is and change it accordingly. And the in the socond one i dont see what s wrong.